# Mongo DB - UpdateMany columns data

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have one database table with a dictionary field which key is string and value is a list of int.(`Dictionary<string,List<int>>())` but now I've changed that dictionary into `(Dictionary<string,list<string>>())`. but the database table has existing records with old dictionary values (`list<int>`).while getting records from the table I got the serialization error. there is any way to update those values from int to string. I mean that will the list of int value replace with a list of string or change int value into a string.
Can i do that with updateMany() mongodb function ?
If yes then how it will be?
here is the one sample record. the assignscopes and scopes are a dictionary

```
{
"_id" : "14390b07-9407-4abb-9504-34eb02d504c1",
"Name" : "Bhavin Varsur",
"UserName" : "b10",
"Email" : "bhavin@gmail.com",
"MobileNumber" : "1016345823",
"Applications" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "19e1b485-3077-49ba-81a2-13dec1abc012",
        "UserRoles" : [ 
            {
                "Name" : "Super Admin",
                "Permissions" : null,
                "AssignScopes" : {
                    "Branch" : [ 
                        0
                    ],
                    "Unit" : [],
                    "Option" : []
                },
                "Scopes" : {
                    "Region" : [ 
                        3
                    ],
                    "Branch" : [ 
                        4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
                    "Unit" : [ 
                        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 44, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 52, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18                            
                    ],
                    "Option" : [ 
                        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

here is the model after change dictionary value as string

```
 public class UserRole
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Permissions { get; set; }
    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> AssignScopes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.Document)]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> Scopes { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can run a pipeline update command with nested map functions like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      Applications: {
        $map: {
          input: "$Applications",
          as: "a",
          in: {
            _id: "$$a._id",
            UserRoles: {
              $map: {
                input: "$$a.UserRoles",
                as: "ur",
                in: {
                  Name: "$$ur.Name",
                  Permissions: "$$ur.Permissions",
                  AssignScopes: {
                    Branch: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$ur.AssignScopes.Branch",
                        as: "b",
                        in: {
                          $toString: "$$b"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    Unit: "$$ur.Unit", // do another map if these are also integers
                    Option: "$$ur.Option" // do another map if these are also integers                    
                  },
                  Scopes: {
                    Region: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$ur.Scopes.Region",
                        as: "r",
                        in: {
                          $toString: "$$r"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    Branch: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$ur.Scopes.Branch",
                        as: "b",
                        in: {
                          $toString: "$$b"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    Unit: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$ur.Scopes.Unit",
                        as: "u",
                        in: {
                          $toString: "$$u"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    Option: {
                      $map: {
                        input: "$$ur.Scopes.Option",
                        as: "o",
                        in: {
                          $toString: "$$o"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/nYqmfBFftPN